# Can we use the same Terraform state file after upgrading Terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am using Terraform `v0.12.31` and planning to upgrade to `v1.2.3` .

I checked one of the Terraform State file -

```
{
  "version": 4,
  "terraform_version": "0.12.31",
  "serial": 2,
  "lineage": "bb737776-5b8a-9771-fa63-453a99ef75dd",
  "outputs": {}
}
```

Terraform version is tied to the state file.
After upgrading Terraform, are the same old state files going to work ?
OR
Is there any way we can make it work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as part of the upgrade process it will update the version in the state file, and possibly update some of the formatting and values in the state file.

I recommend going through the Terraform upgrade guides [here](https://www.terraform.io/language/upgrade-guides).

Comment: After upgrade, if we run just terraform plan, will it update the old state files ?

Comment: No, terraform plan doesn't update the state file. As per the documentation I linked (please read the documentation) it says you will need to run `terraform apply` to update/upgrade the state file as part of the upgrade process.